# EF6 rollback migration in C#

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Lets assume I have 3 migrations in my project:

```
- Initial: sw v1.0.0.0
- M1:      sw v1.2.0.0
- M2:      sw v1.5.0.0
```

Lets assume that one of my customers was using version v1.0, and then this customer received software installation package for v1.5. Customer installed the new version, and when started it, it migrated the database to latest version. No automatic migration is enabled, this was done using the dbMigrator.Update() method.

Lets also assume that v1.5 had a bug, and customer was unable to run this software. At this point we are unable to quickly fix this bug, and the customer should be able to immediately continue using the v1.0.

Customer could uninstall v1.5 and install v1.0, but database would still contain the schema and data from migration M2. So I need somehow to allow customer to rollback from M2 to InitialConfiguration, using c# code, and check for result if migration completed successfully.

I see that most examples include rolling back migration in development environment, using Update-Database command. How can I do the same using c# on a production server, which I do not have access to?

Comment: Did you advise customer to take a back-up of their production environment back upgrading it?

Comment: You can supply a target migration with DbMigrator.Update('Initial'); Another option is just generating a downgrade script that can be applied via SQL from your DEV machine. Update-Database -Script –TargetMigration: Initial

Comment: @ChrisBint This is a hypothetical question, I always like to have a solution for customer in any case.

Comment: @SteveGreene :) Yep, there is an overload. Do you happen to know how can I check if Update("Initial") really worked, and that my currently applied migration is initial (or any other, for that matter)?

Comment: Not sure on that, but all you really need to do is make sure the database and code are in sync. We use a custom IDatabaseInitializer where we check if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)) { -- route to custom error page -- } You can do something similar in your startup code. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Comment: @SteveGreene I cannot use this method (there is GetPendingMigrations() that does similar), since app v1.5 is surely not in sync with #Initial migration. I can use this method with app v1.0, but that would mean I need to uninstall v1.5, reinstall v1.0 and then test it. I could, I guess, use GetDatabaseMigrations() method, and then display to user the latest migration applied. Anyway, feel free to post your first suggestion (overload method), so I can accept it.